# Upgrade to Ubuntu 20 breaking mysqlclient pip package

Tags: django

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tom/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/tom/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/tom/cs344/group8-rw334-project-2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 21, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Before the upgrade I had no issues with mysqlclient. When trying to run my django environment I get this error. I have tried everything I could find online but nothing has worked. I do have the pip package installed.

I have tried completely removing mysqlserver, reinstalling python-dev all the dependencies of the mysqlclient package mentioned on the PyPi page.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands it should help i got the same error and fixed this way.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
pip install mysqlclient
```

Hope it will help